Using Bessel function definition to check the solution of $xy''+(x^2-2)y=0$
I'm working on this exercise:

Using the definition of the Bessel function $J_p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!\;\Gamma (k+p+1)}\Big(\frac{x}{2}\Big)^{2k+p}$ show that for $x>0$ the differential equation $xy''+(x^2-2)y=0$ has the general solution $y(x)=c_1x^{\frac{1}{2}}J_{\frac{3}{2}}(x)+c_2x^{\frac{1}{2}}J_{-\frac{3}{2}}(x)$.

If $y(x)$ is a solution for every value of $c_1$ and $c_2$ I tried to define $c_1=1$ and $c_2=0$ and check if $y(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2}}J_{\frac{3}{2}}(x)$ is a solution. With the definition I have found the second derivative
$$y(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!\;\Gamma (k+\frac{3}{2}+1)}\Big(\frac{x}{2}\Big)^{2k+\frac{3}{2}} =\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!\;\Gamma (k+\frac{5}{2})}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{2k+\frac{3}{2}} x^{2k+2}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k x^{2k+2}$$
$$y''(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k (2k+2)(2k+1)x^{2k}$$
Using those results in the differential equation
$$x\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k (2k+2)(2k+1)x^{2k}+(x^2-2)\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k x^{2k+2} =0$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k (2k+2)(2k+1)x^{2k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k (x^{2k+4}-2x^{2k+2}) =0$$
but here is my problem: the first sum has only odd powers of $x$ and the second one has only even powers so it looks like both terms should be zero by themself. Can you please tell me where is my mistake?

It's a typo. The ODE should be $x^{\color{red}{2}}y''+(x^2-2)y=0$.

That's really annoying. Thanks for the answer.
